# upper and lower integrals piecewise function on [0,1]

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

how do I calculate the upper and lower integrals for a piecewise function:
$ f(x) = 3x $ if x is rational and $ f(x) = -2x$ if not? the interval is [0,1].

Comment: well, you just go ahead and do it. But first you need to specify the interval $[a,b]$ (ooh, I see, it is in the title) . What did you try, did you read the definitions, and some examples? You should use that the rationals, as well as the irrationals are dense in the reals, that is, every interval $[p,q]$ with $p<q$ contains some rationals as well as some irrationals. Answer: $3/2$ and $-1$.

Comment: I wanted a hint because I have never  calculated integrals in a piecewise function,

Comment: since every interval has both rational and irrational numbers in it, we have $U(f,P)=U(3x,P)$ and $L(f,P)=L(-2x,P)$ for all partitions of the interval right? So in my interval it will be for $U(f,P)$ the integral from 0 to 1 of the function 3x?

Comment: what you say is correct, though you should be also be able to explain it in some detail, should your professor ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! very helpful!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: That's not really a "piecewise" function. Yes, it's defined differently in different parts of the domain, but "piecewise" usually means the pieces are disjoint (possibly degenerate) intervals. This isn't official, of course, but it's how the term is usually used in my experience. Not to be nitpicky, but...well...

Comment: I didn't know how else to explain it.. thanks for the info!

Comment: @MPW I wouldn't call this piecewise either, I was thinking of that but wasn't sure what the convention was, and I am happy you confirmed my doubts. One could call this a "case-wise" defined function, yet I would prefer not to call it piece-wise defined. Here the "pieces" are disjoint, one piece the rationals, and the other piece the irrationals, but the problem is that each of the rationals and irrationals is totally disconnected, so each consists itself of many pieces. I guess one tends to expect that a piece would be connected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise

Answer (score 1):

$$U=\int_0^1 3x dx=\frac {3}{2} $$

$$L=\int_0^1-2x dx=-1$$